# FBProphet time range weirdness - adding years at the beginning

Tags: python, pandas, time-series, facebook-prophet

I've been playing with prophet a little. I'm pretty new to Python. Anyway, for some reason when I plot my forecast, its putting 30 rows of dates from 1970 at the beginning. My dates dont start until 2016. I'm definitely screwing up somewhere.
I really just want from 2016-2021. Shouldnt it just start at the earliest date in the dataframe?

```
%matplotlib inline
import pandas as pd
from fbprophet import Prophet

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.style.use('fivethirtyeight')

df = pd.read_csv('sp18.csv',parse_dates=True, skip_blank_lines=True)

(df['ar_balance'].replace( '[\$,)]','', regex=True )
               .replace( '[(]','-',   regex=True ).astype(float))

df.fillna(value=0, method=None, axis=None, inplace=True, limit=None, downcast=None)
df.drop(['day_week', 'ar_balance', 'on_campus', 'online', 'day_num', 'total_cred', 'admissions_event', 'term'], axis = 1, inplace = True)
df.head(5)

Output:

        date    fte
0   11/7/2017   0.0
1   11/8/2017   0.0
2   11/9/2017   0.0
3   11/10/2017  0.0
4   11/11/2017  0.0

df['date'] = pd.DatetimeIndex(df['date'])
df.dtypes

Output:
date    datetime64[ns]
fte            float64
dtype: object

df = df.rename(columns={'date': 'ds',
                        'fte': 'y'})

ax = df.set_index('ds').plot(figsize=(12, 12))
ax.set_ylabel('FTE')
ax.set_xlabel('Date')

plt.show()

my_model = Prophet(interval_width=0.95)
my_model.fit(df)

future_dates = my_model.make_future_dataframe(periods=36)
forecast = my_model.predict(future_dates)
forecast[['ds', 'yhat', 'yhat_lower', 'yhat_upper']].head()

Output:
    ds  yhat    yhat_lower  yhat_upper
0   1970-01-01  48.455828   -1690.768761    1747.227251
1   1970-01-01  48.455828   -1768.346730    1739.514319
2   1970-01-01  48.455828   -1696.532596    1698.719255
3   1970-01-01  48.455828   -1770.763440    1722.128055
4   1970-01-01  48.455828   -1621.479143    1664.295881

    my_model.plot(forecast,
                  uncertainty=True)
    my_model.plot_components(forecast)
    forecast.to_csv('PredictOutput.csv')
```

Here's my jacked up plot. Am I missing something obvious? Thanks for any assistance!

[jacked up plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PxPxR.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suspect that the spurious dates come from NaNs in `df['date']`, which are filled with 0 by the `fillna(value=0)` line, and 0 defaults to 1970-01-01 in `pd.DatetimeIndex` (or in the more flexible `pd.to_datetime(df['date'])`).

To fix this, you'll want to inspect those rows where `date` is null: `df[df['date'].isnull()]`. If these rows hold valid data but are missing date, it may be worth interpolating their date values. But if every row with a null date is entirely null, you can just drop them with `df.dropna(inplace=True)`.

Comment: That's great to hear, and happy coding!